# Leaked GCP FCM Server Keys Your app(s) expose FCM server keys. To address this issue, follow the steps in this Google Help Center article

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-security

I'm using firebase cloud messaging for device to device messaging. before publish app it was working fine but after publish its not working and i got this warning. can anyone help me to fix that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Wtr.png)

Comment: Your keys got leaked. Change your keys.

Comment: Well that might be a bigger job. Your app contains FCM Server keys somewhere in it's sourcecode for example. What google tells you here is that they can't be in your app at all because apps are not trusted environments. You might be doing something like https://androidwave.com/send-fcm-message-from-android/ in your app. Nice Idea but you really can't do that. If you rely on that you'll have to move that out of your app and onto a server backend or find a way to hide those keys so that google can't find them when disassembling your app. FCM = Cloud Messaging, not meant for device to device

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks all of you. that was resolved